# Wiremock admin stub issue

Tags: c#, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I have a stub file that i'm sending via the c# admin api to a standalone wiremock instance. I'm getting the expected response back when i send via postman except the response body is always empty, even though in my file i have this:

```
"Response": {
"Delay": 500,
"UseTransformer": true,
"StatusCode": 205,
"BodyAsJson": { "result": "PRIO = 1 . test" },
"Headers": {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "a": "b"
}
```

}

I see the expected header a b but nothing in the body. Also if i change it to be plain text:

```
"Response": {
"Delay": 500,
"UseTransformer": true,
"StatusCode": 205,
"body": "Hello world!",
"Headers": {
  "Content-Type": "application/text",
  "a": "b"
}
```

This doesn't work either - what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that HTTP **205** does not allow you to return a body? So can you try HTTP **200** ?

See also https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

> 10.2.6 205 Reset Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request and the user agent SHOULD reset
> the document view which caused the request to be sent. This response
> is primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place via
> user input, followed by a clearing of the form in which the input is
> given so that the user can easily initiate another input action. The
> response MUST NOT include an entity.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say looking at the data you have provided what request are you exactly sending to the standalone Wiremock.

The way to investigate the issue would be to hit the [get all mappings endpoint](http://wiremock.org/docs/api/#tag/Stub-Mappings/paths/%7E1__admin%7E1mappings/get) in Wiremock `/__admin/mappings` and check in the response that what you have sent is what is primed in Wiremock.

Comment: The question asked is about the C# .NET version : **WireMock.Net**